# How to add styles to generated Asciidoc HTML returning by Spring Boot controller?

Tags: spring-boot, asciidoc, asciidoctor

The goal is pretty simple: expose documentation in Spring Boot application through separate controller utilizing Thymeleaf template

The documentation is stored in multiple files and will be assembled into single doc with table of contents to the left of the screen

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/documentation")
class DocumentationController {

    private final ModelAndView modelAndView;

    DocumentationController(@Value("classpath*:path/to/documentation/*.adoc") Resource[] docs) {
        Asciidoctor asciidoctor = Asciidoctor.Factory.create();
        Options convertOptions = new Options();
        convertOptions.setToFile(false);
        convertOptions.setSafe(SafeMode.SAFE);

        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Resource doc : docs) {
            try {
                files.add(doc.getFile());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String content = String.join("\n", asciidoctor.convertFiles(files, convertOptions));
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("documentation", "content", content);
    }

    @GetMapping
    ModelAndView documentation() {
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected as of now except the styles: they are absent (which is logical)

How the styles can be added to generated ascii docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This controller generates default Asciidoc document with table of contents to the left of the screen and with default styles

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/documentation")
class DocumentationController {

    private final String content;

    DocumentationController() throws IOException {
        Attributes attributes = AttributesBuilder.attributes()
                .tableOfContents2(Placement.LEFT)
                .sectionNumbers(true)
                .setAnchors(true)
                .get();

        Options options = OptionsBuilder.options()
                .attributes(attributes)
                .toFile(false)
                .headerFooter(true)
                .safe(SafeMode.SAFE)
                .get();

        Asciidoctor asciidoctor = Asciidoctor.Factory.create();
        content = String.join("\n", asciidoctor.convertDirectory(
                new AsciiDocDirectoryWalker(new ClassPathResource("/path/to/documentation")
                        .getURI()
                        .getPath()
                        .replaceFirst("/", "")),
                options));
        asciidoctor.close();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    String documentation() {
        return content;
    }
}
```